# How to rotate only one page in document to landscape in MacOS X Pages?

Tags: macos, macbook, osx-el-capitan, iwork-pages

1. How do I rotate only one page in document to landscape in MacOS X Pages?
2. How do I set up unique style for one page in MacOS X Pages? For example, making specific paddings.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23637), "You can only use one page orientation for your document. Pages doesn't support a mix of portrait and landscape in the same document." As for your second question, I don't think you can set up margins/paddings for a specific page either, although this isn't really explicitly stated on the support page.

One thing you could do would be to select every paragraph on the specific page you want to be different, and then adjust the margins with either the ruler or in the Layout tab in the toolbar. I realise this isn't nearly as convenient, but it might be an option you want to explore.

Comment: They've done it somehow in the Modern Resume, I can't for the life of me figure out how. If you create a new document based on this template and add some more content to get a second page, somehow the second page has a reduced margin from the body to the top of the page. Any idea how to change this margin?

Comment: Sorry, meant the Modern Resume template.

Comment: Gah, Business Resume!

Comment: Interestingly - after a moment of shock - this makes complete sense.  I wanted a single page in Landscape for a large picture.  All I needed was rotate the image by holding the CMD button and hovering over the middle-bottom of image.  Same result with less complexity of doc formatting.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the page layout in Pages, I have to tell you there is no way as off yet to do that.